# Last iteration returns undefined

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, undefined

When looping through this string, the alert prints out test 4 times (correctly) but then also prints "undefined" at the end. How do I make it doesn't return undefined.

This returns - undefinedCAFE ::

```
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));


function match(string, pattern) {

    var patternUpperCase = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var stringUpperCase = string.toUpperCase();
    var stringConcatenate;
    var answer;

    for (var i = 0; i < patternUpperCase.length; i++) {
        if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) != undefined) {
            if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) >= 'A' && patternUpperCase.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                stringConcatenate += patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
                alert("test");
            }
        }
    }
    return stringConcatenate;
}
```

This is what the function needs to do: returns true if all the individual LETTERS of pattern appear in string (regardless of order) (case insensitive)

Examples
    match("abcdef","@C2D!") returns true
    match("abcdef","CAfe") returns true
    match("abcdef","CG") returns false

Comment: Note that `.charAt()` never returns undefined. If the index is out of bounds, empty string (eg. `""`) is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your error happens because you're contactenating uninitialised string with some other string.

This line (for the first iteration):

```
stringConcatenate += patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
```

Where **`stringConcatenate`** has not be initialised reads as:

```
stringConcatenate = "undefined" + patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
```

**So do this in your code:**

```
var stringConcatenate = "";
```

**Small note to accessing characters of strings:**
If you use `String.charAt()` method, your test for return value should be folowing:

```
if(somestring.charAt(x)!="") 
   ... valid
```

However, you can also access offsets in string via array operator `[x]`. This one indeed returs `undefined`:

```
if(typeof somestring[x]!="undefined")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the regex functions?

```
alert( !/[^pattern]/.test(string) );
```

Or to make it comply with the @ sign:

```
alert( !/[^pattern]/.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/, '').test(string) );
```

The last example removes everything apart from a-z (lower and upper), and then test if any forbidden characters are in the remaining string.

Because this will give a `true` when it finds a 'wrong'  character, reverse it with the `!`

Comment: I guess he is trying to implement the functionality by himself on purpose. Also, regex would be significantly slower.

Comment: @Martijn we have not yet learnt regex in my university class so I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

Set stringConcatenate as a string variable first.

```
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));


function match(string, pattern) {

    var patternUpperCase = pattern.toUpperCase();
    var stringUpperCase = string.toUpperCase();
    var stringConcatenate = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < patternUpperCase.length; i++) {
        if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) != undefined) {
            if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) >= 'A' && patternUpperCase.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                stringConcatenate += patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
                console.log(stringConcatenate);
            }
        }
    }
    return stringConcatenate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes:
1. stringConcatenate was not initialized.
2. your code was incomplete, as it didn't check the condition where the pattern's letter is present in the 'string'.

This should solve your problem:

```
function fooo(){
str = "abcdsdfef";
pattern = "d234g4f";
var patternUpperCase = pattern.toUpperCase();
var stringUpperCase = str.toUpperCase();
var stringConcatenate="";
var answer = true;

for (var i = 0; i < patternUpperCase.length; i++) {
    if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) != undefined) {
        if (patternUpperCase.charAt(i) >= 'A' && patternUpperCase.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
            stringConcatenate += patternUpperCase.charAt(i);
    if(stringUpperCase.indexOf(patternUpperCase.charAt(i)) == -1){
        answer = false;
        break;
    }
        }
    }
}
alert(answer);
```

}